# Getting Error while launching the given cloudformation template in us-east-1 region. ( Build lambda Function receives error)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

Error: The Build Lambda Function receives the following error.

AccessDeniedExceptionnull (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 7a8c9e0e-61db-403b-9448-0f5e61beddd4; Proxy: null)

I am trying to run a cloudformation template using below link. While the stack is executing it rollbacks giving above mentioned error.

What may be the probable cause for this issue??

Using this git repo:https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-machine-learning-on-aws

using this cloudformation template link:https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stacks/new?stackName=serverless-ml&templateURL=https://aws-ml-blog.s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts/serverless-machine-learning-on-aws/template.json

using this blog for creating cloudformation template:https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploying-machine-learning-models-as-serverless-apis/

Comment: Which resources you get this exception for?

Comment: linking issue opened for this: https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-machine-learning-on-aws/issues/9

Comment: @PatMyron, I have opened that issue, so that someone from the git repo responds. I am hoping that people here on stackoverflow respond faster. Is there any way you could help ?

Comment: @Marcin, the Build lambda function fails with above error.
do I have to import some code in s3 bucket or for the default template, whatever is specified is good enough. If you are aware, do let me know.

Comment: I tried running the cloudformation template in other aws account and it works. anyone aware why it is not working on my account. is there anything to do with iam ?? if someone's aware please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has something to do with the default vpc not being correctly configured in the particular region.
If you try with any other region or another aws account it will definitely work.